# Extract Numeric Data from a Text file in Python

Tags: python, string, extract

Say I have a text file with the data/string:

```
Dataset #1: X/Y= 5, Z=7 has been calculated
Dataset #2: X/Y= 6, Z=8 has been calculated
Dataset #10: X/Y =7, Z=9 has been calculated
```

I want the output to be on a csv file as:

```
X/Y, X/Y, X/Y
```

Which should display:

```
5, 6, 7
```

Here is my current approach, I am using string.find, but I feel like this is rather difficult in solving this problem:

```
data = open('TestData.txt').read()
#index of string
counter = 1

if (data.find('X/Y=')==1):      
#extracts segment out of string
    line = data[r+6:r+14]
    r = data.find('X/Y=')
    counter += 1 
    print line
else: 
    r = data.find('X/Y')`enter code here`
    line = data[r+6:r+14]
    for x in range(0,counter):
    print line


print counter
```

Error: For some reason, I'm only getting the value of 5. when I setup a #loop, i get infinite 5's.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want the numbers and your txt file is  formatted like the first two lines i.e `X/Y= 6`, not like `X/Y =7`:

```
import re
result=[]
with open("TestData.txt") as f:
    for line in f:
        s = re.search(r'(?<=Y=\s)\d+',line) # pattern matches up to "Y" followed by "=" and a space "\s" then a digit or digits. 
        if s: # if there is a match i.e re.search does not return None, add match to the list.
            result.append(s.group())
print result
['5', '6', '7']
```

To match the pattern in your comment, you should escape the period like . or you will match strings like 1.2+3 etc.. the "." has special meaning re.

So  `re.search(r'(?<=Counting Numbers =\s)\d\.\d\.\d',s).group()`
will return only `1.2.3`

If it makes it more explicit, you can use  `s=re.search(r'(?<=X/Y=\s)\d+',line)` using the full `X/Y=\s` pattern.

Using the original line in your comment and updated line would return :

```
['5', '6', '7', '5', '5']
```

The  `(?<=Y=\s`)is called a *positive lookbehind assertion*.

```
(?<=...)
```

*Matches if the current position in the string is preceded by a match for ... that ends at the current position*

There are lots of nice examples [here in the re documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html). The items in the parens are not returned.

Comment: So how would this work for a more complex text file? Say that I now have an extra Y in my text file: 


Dataset #1: Y=2, X/Y= 5, Z=7 has been calculated

Comment: I added the output, what comes before is irrelevant, all we are looking for is `Y= 5`, Yes does not match our pattern

Comment: Sorry, I just updated my comment, I get the arguments now. Thanks a lot for clearing that up with me. 

Would you be able to observe the updated comment?

Say I have Dataset #1: Y= 2, X/Y= 5 has been calculated.

But I want to only have the value of X/Y= 5

Comment: @user3685687, again it will work as the pattern has to have Y= 5.

Comment: Is there a way to make the Pattern X/Y= ?

Comment: I just added that to my answer a minute ago to make it more explicit

Comment: Thank you Padraic! That helped a lot. I'll be looking into that regex command website

Comment: You're welcome. The syntax can seem daunting at first but once you use it a few times you will be flying along.

Comment: Hi @Padraic Cunningham,

I am writing to question, so if I have data: 

Counting Numbers = 1.2.3

Would i do:
 re.search(r'(<?<=Counting\sNumbers\s=\s)\d.\d.\d))?

Comment: @user3685687, I added to my answer

Answer (score 1):

Since it appears that the entities are all on a single line, I would recommend using `readline` in a `loop` to read the file line-by-line and then using a `regex` to parse out the components you're looking for from that line.

**Edit re: OP's comment:**

One regex pattern that could be used to capture the number given the specified format in this case would be: `X/Y\s*=\s*(.+),`

Comment: When using regex to parse out the components, what exactly would you use for the regex arguments?

r= re.compile("^X/Y=|,$")?

Comment: Got it! That helped clear up the question I had in the bottom solution. Thank you!